# ffmpeg - 'Unable to find a suitable output format for 'libfdk_aac''

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel info -threads 0 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -framerate 60 -i image.jpg -start_number 000000 -apply_trc bt709 -framerate 60 -i /myseq.%06d.exr -r 60 -preset medium -codec:v libx264 -profile:v main -tune fastdecode-c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -vbr 5 -shortest -strict experimental -sn -vsync 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 31457280 -movflags +faststart -vf scale=3072:1536 -map "2:0" -map "0:0" /output.mp4 2>&1 | tee -a /log_file.log
```

And i get the following error:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'libfdk_aac'
```

Any idea why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a space missing in `-tune fastdecode-c:a libfdk_aac`, so FFmpeg thinks the value of tune is `fastdecode-c:a` and thus the next word is the output filename. Insert space after `fastdecode`.